# Filter by AR support on Google Play Developer Console?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore, google-play-console, android-augmented-reality

I am looking to work on an Augmented Reality (AR) app using Google ARCore/Google Play AR services, as a bolt-on targeting the user-base of one of our current apps which is used by a very large group of people.

For obvious reasons, I would like to filter the current user devices to see what % of our current audience can use AR on their android phone. Is there any way to do this? I can export the device list from Google Play Developer Console.

Answer (score 0):

Just answered this one for myself oops, go to the Device Catalogue - Filter by system feature: android.hardware.camera.ar